# jQuery element value = $(this).value

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to select the element with class of Level1 whose value is equal to $(this).val().  I read that you can't do $(.Level1[someAttribute=value]) which makes sense as val() isn't an available DOM attribute in that sense.  This may be an easy one, but I am stumped at the moment.  **Unfortunately i do not have the ability to change how the HTML below is rendered.**

```
$('.Level0').each(function () {
   var sortOfChildren = $('.Level1').val() = $(this).val //not real code

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="Row Level0 PCITrainingVerification">x</div>
<div class="Row Level1 PCITrainingVerification">x</div>
<div class="Row Level1 PCITrainingVerification">x</div>
<div class="Row Level1 PCITrainingVerification">x</div>
<div class="Row Level1 PCITrainingVerification">x</div>
<div class="Row Level0 Training2">y</div>
<div class="Row Level0 Training3">z</div>
<div class="Row Level1 Training3">z</div>
```

**ANSWER**

```
$('.Level0').each(function () {
    var targetValue = $(this).val();
    var matching = $(".Level1").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === targetValue;
    });
    // ...use `matching` here...
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what$(this).val() is though?

Comment: You've referred to the "value" of these elements -- but none of them is a form field! What do you mean by "value"?

Comment: also divs do not have value associated to them

Comment: I updated question based on comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question talks about [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) and the "value" of elements, but none of the elements in your question is a form field, and therefore they don't *have* values.

**If they were form fields**:

> I read that you can't do $(.Level1[someAttribute=value]) which makes sense as val() isn't an available DOM attribute in that sense

Right, your only option is to loop, probably via [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('.Level0').each(function () {
    var targetValue = $(this).val();
    var matching = $(".Level1").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === targetValue;
    });
    // ...use `matching` here...
});
```

Note that `matching` may have zero, or multiple, elements in it depending on how many `.Level1` elements matched the value.

**But because they aren't**:

...you may want [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) instead of `.val` in the above, or possibly a [`:contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) instead of `filter`.

Comment: Excellent! This works perfectly.  I will use either text or html instead of val()